# error of streaming video using fluent-ffmpeg node.js module

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, flowplayer

I am running the fluent-ffmpeg [sample](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg) to stream the video, which works well. Now in contract show the video in flashe version based flowplayer, I am now using html5 version flowplayer, but it said the video file not found.

```
app.get('/video2/abc', function(req, res) {

  console.log('/video/:filename');
  res.contentType('mp4');
  var pathToMovie = 'public/flowplayer/470x250.mp4' ; 
  var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: pathToMovie, nolog: true })
    .writeToStream(res, function(retcode, error){
      if(error) console.error('error',error); 
      else console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
    });
});
```

here is my html template.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/skin/minimalist.css" />
        <title>node-fluent-ffmpeg</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <script>
   // global configuration (optional)
   flowplayer.conf = {
      rtmp: "rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
      swf: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/flowplayer.swf"
   };

   // force flash with query - only for testing, do not use this switch in production!
   if (/flash/.test(location.search)) flowplayer.conf.engine = "flash";

   // install player manually
   $(function() {
      $(".player").flowplayer({
         // reverse fraction of video aspect ratio
         // video dimensions: 470px / 250px
         ratio: 25/47
      });
   });
</script>
    <div class="flowplayer">
        <video>
           <source type="video/mp4" src="/video2/your_movie"/>
        </video>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and decided to use video-js instead. Which worked perfectly out of the box.

Check it out: http://www.videojs.com/

In my case I inject the video tag with jquery and dynamically load the video. like so:

```
    //I append the video tag so I remove it if I already appended it before.
    if($('#player').length) $('#player').remove();


    $('body').append('<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" poster="my_video_poster.png" data-setup="{}"> <source src="'+url+'" type="video/webm"></video>');

    // Load the player dynamically. see: http://www.videojs.com/docs/setup/
    _V_("player", {}, function(){});
```